# Ruby Spell Checker Not Working Properly

Tags: ruby, spell-checking

I am writing a small project in ruby that takes all of the words from a website and then sorts them short to long.

To verify that what gets sorted is actually valid english I am comparing an array of scraped words to the basic unix/osx words file.

The method to do this is the `spell_check` method. The problem is that when used on small arrays is works fine, but with larger ones it will let non-words through. Any ideas?

```
def spell_check (words_array)
  dictionary = IO.read "./words.txt"
  dictionary = dictionary.split 
  dictionary.map{|x| x.strip }

  words_array.each do |word|
    if !(dictionary.include? word)
      words_array.delete word
    end 
  end 

  return words_array
end
```

Comment: what is in words.txt? You do not pass a parameter to split, is this intentional? did you mean splice?

Comment: What is an example of a "non-word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code, maybe this will work?

```
def spell_check(words)
  lines = IO.readlines('./words.txt').map { |line| line.strip }
  words.reject { |word| !lines.include? word }
end
```

I noticed that you were trying to modify the `words_array` while you were simultaneously iterating over it with `each`:

```
words_array.each do |word|
  if !(dictionary.include? word)
    words_array.delete word # Delete the word from words_array while iterating!
  end 
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the case in Ruby, but in other programming languages like Java and C#, trying to modify a collection, while you're iterating over it at the same time, invalidates the iteration, and either produces unexpected behavior, or just throws an error. Maybe this was your problem with your original code?

Also, the `return` statement was unnecessary in your original code, because the last statement evaluated in a Ruby block is always returned (unless there's an explicit `return` that precedes the last statement). It's idiomatic Ruby to leave it out in such cases.

Comment: You are absolutely right that modifying an array while iterating over it in Ruby causes problems. It won't throw an error, but some elements in the array will never be yielded by `each`.

Comment: @AlexD I've been trying to find a reference for that in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html), but so far no luck, do you know of any official references that can be used as a supporting citation?

Comment: No, but this is well-known to experienced Ruby programmers. Looking at the source code for `Array#each` makes the problem very obvious: `VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
 rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}`

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. I am new to Ruby and I suspected that this was the case. Thanks again!